# Handling backreferences to capturing groups in re.sub replacement pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to take the string `0.71331, 52.25378` and return `0.71331,52.25378` - i.e. just look for a digit, a comma, a space and a digit, and strip out the space.

This is my current code:

```
coords = '0.71331, 52.25378'
coord_re = re.sub("(\d), (\d)", "\1,\2", coords)
print coord_re
```

But this gives me `0.7133,2.25378`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you don't actually want to capture the digits, it may make more sense to use look-arounds, i.e.: `re.sub(r'(?<=\d), (?=\d)', ',', coords)`.

Comment: This particular question doesn't need regex, use replace:  `coords.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: @GringoSuave the question is not to replace/eliminate *all* white spaces. It is only when the space is between (digit)(comma) and (digit). For that, regex is the right choice.

Comment: There is no other whitespace, but if there was you'd probably want to remove it too.  Overuse of regex is an issue—don't use unless actually needed.  Removing a space: no, parsing a telephone number: yes.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You should be using raw strings for regex, try the following:

```
coord_re = re.sub(r"(\d), (\d)", r"\1,\2", coords)
```

With your current code, the backslashes in your replacement string are escaping the digits, so you are replacing all matches the equivalent of `chr(1) + "," + chr(2)`:

```
>>> '\1,\2'
'\x01,\x02'
>>> print '\1,\2'
,
>>> print r'\1,\2'   # this is what you actually want
\1,\2
```

Any time you want to leave the backslash in the string, use the `r` prefix, or escape each backslash (`\\1,\\2`).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation for anyone reading this.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-rstring-flags-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-litte/2081708#2081708 for a better explanation of what raw strings are.

Comment: How would you actually print the group name in the example above? Say, if group `\1` where called *xCoord*, is it possible to instruct `re.sub` to replace the sub strings with group names such that `re.sub(r"(\d), (\d)", r"\1,\2", coords)` resulted in the string literal `xCoord,52.25378`

Comment: This doesn't work in Python3. Using `\1` replaces it with some bizarre unicode character.

Answer (score 30):

Python interprets the `\1` as a character with ASCII value 1, and passes that to `sub`.

Use raw strings, in which Python doesn't interpret the `\`.

```
coord_re = re.sub(r"(\d), (\d)", r"\1,\2", coords)
```

This is covered right in the beginning of the [`re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), should you need more info.