# Python re.sub specific syntax

Tags: python, linux, scripting

I am writing a script in python that replaces specific lines in files Linux.  Say i have a file called hi in the /home directory that contains:

```
hi 873840
```

Here is my script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import re

fp = open("/home/hi","w")
re.sub(r"hi+", "hi 90", fp)
```

My desired outcome is:

```
hi 90
```

however, when i run it i get this error and the hi file ends up being balnk:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 6, in <module>
    re.sub(r"hi+", "hi 90", fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
 TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?
Thanks

Comment: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`: third parameter is a string not a file pointer thats why you are getting error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace string in file with using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688126/replace-string-in-file-with-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

use `"r"` more to read file, `"w"` mode will create empty file for writing. `.readline()` will get and pass the string to the `re.sub()`. `r" .*"` will return a string you want to replace after the `'space'` character. i assume `'hi 873840'` is the only text in your file and your desired output is only `'hi 90'`

```
echo "hi 873840" > hi.txt

python3.6

import re
fp = open("hi.txt", "r")
print(re.sub(r" .*", " 90", fp.readline()))
```

Comment: Text that describe the solution you've come up with would be useful to the person who asked the question.

Comment: thank for the reminder and suggestion. new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file in read mode. [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) expects three arguments, `pattern, repl, string`. The problem is the third argument you are passing is a file pointer.
Eg:

```
import re
with open('/home/hi', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    for line in infile:
       print(re.sub(r"hi+", "hi 90", line.strip()))
```