# I have a string "192.192", why am I not able to match this using '(\d{1,3})\.\1'?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

String in question:

`ipAddressString = "192.192.10.5/24"`

I'm trying to match 192.192 in the above string.

a) The below code gives error, I don't understand why \1 is not matching the second 192:

```
>>> print re.search('(\d{1,3})\.\1',ipAddressString).group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I was expecting the output to be : 192.192

b) Whereas, when I use the below regex, it matches 192.192 as expected, as per my understanding the above regex mentioned in point a) should have yielded the same ".group()" output as below regex

```
>>> print re.search('(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})',ipAddressString).group()
192.192
```

Comment: Try using a raw string `print (re.search(r'(\d{1,3})\.\1',ipAddressString))` https://ideone.com/TSCCkW

Comment: `\1` in `'(\d{1,3})\.\1'`  is a char with octal number 1, a SOH (*Start Of Heading*) char. `r'\1'` is a backreference, a combination of ``\`` and `1` chars.

Comment: Plus one simply for teaching me about the existence of group backreferences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling backreferences to capturing groups in re.sub replacement pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157267/handling-backreferences-to-capturing-groups-in-re-sub-replacement-pattern)

Comment: @mx0 - What's the title of that link ? Is it _Backreferences in string Parsing_ ? If its _not_ then it is not a  duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List of escape sequences available in Python 3](https://www.quackit.com/python/reference/python_3_escape_sequences.cfm)

Those are the escapes interpolated when parsing a string in Python.
All other escaped items are ignored.

So, if you give it a string  like `'(\d{1,3})\.\1'`
it interpolates the `\1` as a character with an *octal value* of 1.

> \ooo Character with octal value ooo

So this is what you get

```
>>> import re
>>> ipAddressString = "192.192.10.5/24"
>>> hh = re.search('(\d{1,3})\.\1',ipAddressString)
>>> print (hh)
None
>>> print ('(\d{1,3})\.\1')
(\d{1,3})\.☺
```

The regex engine sees this `(\d{1,3})\.☺` which is not an error
but it doesn't match what you want.

Ways around this:

- Escape the escape on the *octal*
  `'(\d{1,3})\.\\1'`
- Make the string a raw string with syntax
  either a raw double `r"(\d{1,3})\.\1"` or a raw single `r'(\d{1,3})\.\1'`

Using the first method we get:

```
>>> import re
>>> ipAddressString = "192.192.10.5/24"
>>> hh = re.search('(\d{1,3})\.\\1',ipAddressString)
>>> print (hh)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='192.192'>
>>> print ('(\d{1,3})\.\\1')
(\d{1,3})\.\1
```

Just a side note, most regex engines also recognize octal sequences.
But to differentiate an octal from a back reference it usually requires a leading `\0`then a 2 or 3 digit octal `\0000-\0377` for example, but sometimes it doesn't and will accept both.

Thus, there is a gray area of overlap.

Some engines will mark the back reference (example `\2`) when it finds
an ambiguity, then when finished parsing the regex, revisit the item
and mark it as a back reference if the group exists, or an octal
if it doesn't. Perl is famous for this.

In general, each engine handles the issue of *octal vs back reference*
in it's own bizarre way. Its always a gotcha waiting to happen.