# re.sub using replacement text from dict

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Can replacement text in re.sub retrieve values from a dictionary?

In the same spirit as another SO's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157267/handling-backreferences-to-capturing-groups-in-re-sub-replacement-pattern), with the code

```
coord_re = re.sub(r"(\d), (\d)", r"\1,\2", coords)
```

I want to use backreferences in a replacement string as well, except that I want to use string that was referred as \1,\2 as a key to obtain value from some dictionary

For example, I want something similar to this:

```
d = {...somedict}
coord_re = re.sub(r"(\d), (\d)", d[value of \1]+','+d[value of \2], coords)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda` or functions in `re.sub`:

```
import re

d = {
    '1': 'a',
    '2': 'b'
}

print( re.sub('(\d), (\d)', lambda g: d[g.group(1)] + ', ' + d[g.group(2)], '1, 2') )
```

Prints:

```
a, b
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string. For example: