# findall and replace instances including markers

Tags: python, string, replace, findall, confluence-rest-api

I am using Python 3.7.9 and I have some kind of HTML code which includes some data from pandas table. I'd like to color specific data from pandas table and therefore I'd like to re-use the text between a string marker and replace it with some other markers (they are used in Confluence to mark the text in a specific color.)

My input text string is:

`text = 'some text now important information starts decrease-123456decrease more text not to touch next marker increase7896278689increase and more text another marker decrease-12355decrease with important information'`

The replacement strings are:

```
increase = '<span style=\"color: Red;\">'+val+'</span>'
decrease = '<span style=\"color: Green;\">'+val+'</span>'
```

and val is the information to be found between the markers.

So my expected output is:

```
output = some text now important information starts <span style=\"color: Green;\">-123456</span> more text not to touch next marker <span style=\"color: Red;\">7896278689</span> and more text another marker <span style="color: Green;">-12355</span> with important information
```

Here is what I tried:

```
import re

text = 'some text now important information starts decrease-123456decrease more text not to touch next marker increase7896278689increase and more text another marker decrease-12355decrease with important information'
found_increase = re.findall('increase(.+?)increase', text)
found_decrease = re.findall('decrease(.+?)decrease',text)
output=''
for i, val in enumerate(found_increase):
    output=text.replace('increase'+val+'increase', '<span style=\"color: Red;\">'+val+'</span>')
for i, val in enumerate(found_decrease):
    output=text.replace('decrease'+val+'decrease', '<span style=\"color: Green;\">'+val+'</span>')
print(output)
```

I have also tried the styles methodology which comes with pandas, but Confluence is not real HTML and therefore this approach does not work for me. In my above example I get the following output:

`Some text now important information starts decrease-123456decrease more text not to touch next marker increase7896278689increase and more text another marker <span style="color: Green;">-12355</span> with important information`

Comment: Hi, maybe you can have a look to re.sub in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this code worked instead:

```
print(re.sub(r"decrease(.*?)decrease", r"<span style=\"color: Green;\">\1</span>", test))
```

What's happening here is we are replacing the pattern

```
"decrease(.*?)decrease"
```

with

```
"<span style=\"color: Green;\">\1</span>"
```

where `\1` is the content of `(.*?)`. Notice the leading `r` before the string. You can read about why that's there [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8157317/11659881).

Obviously, you need to recreate this for the increase version as well.

Note that `replace()` [will replace all occurences](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp), it looks like your code didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

The python regex engine directly supports replacement through capture groups and `re.sub`/`re.Pattern.sub`. The default is to replace all occurrences of the pattern.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

The pattern to access the first capture group is `r'\1'` or `'\\1'` respectively

```py
import re
text = 'some text now important information starts decrease-123456decrease more text not to touch next marker increase7896278689increase and more text another marker decrease-12355decrease with important information'
inc_replaced = re.sub('increase(.+?)increase', '<span style=\"color: Red;\">\\1</span>', text)
output = re.sub('decrease(.+?)decrease', '<span style=\"color: Green;\">\\1</span>', text)
```

```
>>> output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
'some text now important information starts <span style="color: Green;">-123456</span> more text not to touch next marker increase7896278689increase and more text another marker <span style="color: Green;">-12355</span> with important information'
```