# Find all <a href> HTML tags and append target blank values using Python regular expression

Tags: python, append

I want to find all

```
<a href='https://example.com/'>
```

references in a large file and append the

```
target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'
```

option to the end of the  tag, if it is missing.

Roughly, I did the following:

```
re.sub(r'<a href=([^>]+)', r'<a href=([^>]+)' + " target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'", content)
```

Note: content contains the body of text to alter.

But, the second argument, which should be the value to replace is messing up the result.

The output I am getting is:

```
<a href=([^>]+) target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
```

The expected result should be:

```
<a href='https://example.com/' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
```

What am I doing incorrectly, and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: No it does not. I am specifically looking for <a href> tags. Also the regex pattern is finding the text I want. I'm hitting a dead-end trying to append text to each value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling backreferences to capturing groups in re.sub replacement pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157267/handling-backreferences-to-capturing-groups-in-re-sub-replacement-pattern)

Comment: `<a href=([^>]+)` makes no sense as _replacement_ text.  I believe you want `\1`, meaning "the text that matched the first capture group pattern".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:     (*** If coding professionally, use the tool ti7 suggested.)

```
import re
content = "<a href='https://example.com/'>"
x = re.sub(r'(<a href=([^>]+))', r'\1' + " target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'", content)
print(x)

output:
   <a href='https://example.com/' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem I had. Can you briefly mention why is BeautifulSoup a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a 3rd-party library, BeautifulSoup may work very well for you!
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, "html.parser")
soup.find_all("a")
```